# Expo in app purchases implementation issues

Tags: react-native, expo

I am struggling a little with getting in app purchases working due to lack of examples that show how all the functionality links together

In my app, I have one in app purchase which basically allows the user to unlock some restricted functionality for life.

So at the start I want to check if the user have purchased the item before. (via get history)

If they have I unlock the functionality.

On my signed APK file (android) made in android studio, I have the following issues:

-the purchase never acknowledges (although it does when run via react-native run-android)
-if you press the purchase button twice the error "already connected to app store appears"
-I don't think its getting the purchase history when running from the signed file (although I can print out the result in the console in debug mode)

I am not entirely sure when to call await InAppPurchases.connectAsync(); so this could be one potential source of issues

So this is my code in my "Inner App" . My App component is just the InnerApp wrapped in the provider component from redux. The inner app contains all the navigation stacks so the purchase listener should be global.

e.g.

```
 export default function App (){
 
 ...more code
 
 return(
 < Provider store={store}  >
 < InnerApp />
 </ Provider  >
 }
```

Inner app code

```
 import * as InAppPurchases from 'expo-in-app-purchases';
 
 export default function InnerApp (){

 .....some more code
 
 //gets purchase history
  const getHistory = async ()=>{ 
   await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
   let found=false
   const { responseCode, results } = await InAppPurchases.getPurchaseHistoryAsync();
   
 if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.OK) {
   results.forEach(result => {
   
     if (result.acknowledged) {
    found =true 
    // this is just saving to local storage (in case they are using the app offline)
    savePurchaseHistory(true)
    }else{
    
    savePurchaseHistory(false)
    }
   });
 }
 if( found){
 //updates a state in the redux store
 dispatch(purchaseIAP() )
 }else if(responseCode === IAPResponseCode.USER_CANCELED ){
  
  dispatch(removeIAP() )
 savePurchaseHistory(false)
 }
 await InAppPurchases.disconnectAsync();
 }
 //listens for purchases
  const setUpIAP = async() => {
     // Set purchase listener
     await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
     await InAppPurchases.setPurchaseListener(({ responseCode, results, errorCode }) => {
       // Purchase was successful
       if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.OK) {
         results.forEach(purchase => {
           if (!purchase.acknowledged) {
             
             // Process transaction here and unlock content...
            dispatch(purchaseIAP() )
             // Then when you're done
             InAppPurchases.finishTransactionAsync(purchase, false);
           }
         });
       }
 
       // Else find out what went wrong
       if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
       } else if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.DEFERRED) {

         console.log('User does not have permissions to buy but requested parental approval (iOS only)');
       } else {
    
         console.warn(`Something went wrong with the purchase. Received errorCode ${errorCode}`);
       }
     });
 }
 
 
  
   //The in app stuff is called when the component is mounted
  useEffect(() => {      
      setUpIAP()
 getHistory()
   }, [ ] })
```

Further in my app I have a button that calls the following function when pressed

```
 const unlockModes = async () => {
   
   try {
     const items = Platform.select({
   ios: [
     'dev.products.all_modes'
   ],
   android: ['all_modes'],
 });
     await connectAsync();
     const products = await InAppPurchases.getProductsAsync(items);
 
     if (products.results.length > 0) {
      
       await InAppPurchases.purchaseItemAsync("all_modes");
     } 
   } catch (err) {
     
     alert("error occured while trying to purchase: " + err);
   }
 };
```

Comment: It would seem that the main issue is that in the signed APK it doesnt seem to resolve connectAsync() but have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the React Native IAP library and I couldn't get the expo one to work.

I think the Expo Version currently might just be bust.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `useGooglePlayCache` will resolve your problem